# Как добавить в проверку email конкретные tld?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярное выражение, которое проверяет email:

```
email: (value) => {
    const pattern = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return pattern.test(value) || "Invalid e-mail.";
},
```

Что необходимо добавить в него/ изменить в нем, чтобы доступные вводимые имейлы могли заканчиваться только на 2 возможных tld: com или ukr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что нужно знать в таких случаях, так это где нужно ввести изменение. Для этого нужно понять, как работает регулярное выражение, выявить его составные компоненты и ограничить ту часть, которая нужна.

На сайте regex101.com в режиме PCRE можно включить опцию `extended` (флаг `x`) и разбить регулярное выражение по строкам, вот что у меня получилось:

```js
^
(
  [^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*|".+"
)
@
(
  \[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}]|([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}
)
$
```

См. [пример на regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sCKgOa/6). Да, я удалил ненужные скобки, где они ничего не группировали.

Сразу становится ясно, что `[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*|".+"` нас не интересует, эта часть отвечает за имя пользователя. Смотрим, что стоит за `@`. А там `\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}]|([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}`, чередование двух шаблонов.

`\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}]` находит IP в квадратных скобках, и это снова не наш шаблон. Зато `([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}` - то, что нужно.

**Замените `[a-zA-Z]{2,}` на `(?:ukr|com)`**, и дело с концом:

```js
^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}]|([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+(?:com|ukr))$
```

См. [пример регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/sCKgOa/5).

Comment: работает,спасибо за развернутый ответ!